# Python PIL message lost in compress

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, steganography

I am trying some basic steganography (hiding text in a picture) in Python using the PIL module. I write a message, convert it to binary and then depending on each binary character change the RGB of each pixel to be odd or even, to represent a 1 or 0. This all works fine, but when the changed image is saved it is compressed in a way that the rgb value is changed during compression.

Was wondering if anyone knew a workaround for this?

Comment: Do you have a sample image, code etc.?

Comment: Save it as PNG rather than JPEG. That will make it lossless.